# SQL - Select all teams that wore exactly two different shirt colors?

Tags: sql

I have this table:

Playing(Date,Time,Location,Name,TeamName,ShirtColor)

And I want to select all teams that wore exactly two different shirt colors.

Since I dont have SQL DB, I'd like to ask which of these two (or maybe none of them) is correct and why?

1. `SELECT (DISTINCT TeamName)

   FROM Playing

   WHERE TeamName IN (SELECT TeamName FROM Playing GROUP BY TeamName HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2)`
2. `SELECT (DISTINCT TeamName)

   FROM Playing

   WHERE TeamName IN (SELECT TeamName FROM Playing WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2 GROUP BY ShirtColor)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of your queries are correct from a syntactic point of view.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/149ea/4)** with sample data, and with the query that you are looking for

```
SELECT TeamName 
FROM Playing 
GROUP BY TeamName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2
```

When you GROUP records, the conditions for your aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, AVG etc.) need to be used in a `HAVING` statement.

Your **first query** is correct, if you eliminate the parentheses from `(DISTINCT TeamName)`, although as **ypercube** mentioned, it is a bit overcomplicated, but functionally correct.

Whereas your **second query** will not work, because the

`SELECT TeamName FROM Playing WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2` part is not correct. As I have mentioned previously, your conditions on aggregate functions (in your case `COUNT`) have to be used in a `HAVING` statement.

Comment: @jyparask You're right, but I didn't finish editing my question.

Comment: hehe, it is ok...I just saw it and i thought i should mention it.

Comment: The first OP's query is (overcomplicated but) correct - if the parentheses are removed from the first line: `SELECT DISTINCT TeamName ...`

Comment: @ypercube You're right, I missed that. I only ran his queries and saw that they have syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT TeamName 
FROM Playing 
GROUP BY TeamName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to use aggregates to filter data then you should use `HAVING` clause. The `WHERE` clause will throw an error.

So in your case No2 is not correct.

No1 has a `subquery` that returns all those teams that have exactly two different colors. That part is correct. But then you have a select that has no meaning. You could just use:

```
SELECT TeamName FROM Playing GROUP BY TeamName HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ShirtColor) = 2
```